# log missed while cron run

Tags: magento2, log, magento-cron

I have created cron which is scheduled for every 5 mins.In the cron,based on some conditions I have inserted value to custom table, while insert I have logged value in custom log file.For sometimes ,the value is not logged in the custom log file .But the value was correctly inserted into table.Why sometimes the value is logged in custom log file?

Comment: This happens because Magento misses some executions when it comes to cron tasks. Sometimes it's executed, sometimes it's not (depending on many factors). If it's critical, I would suggest adding the task directly in the system cron, not magentos. Try installing an extension like this: https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-cron-schedule to see whether the magento cron is missing some executions or not.

Comment: If cron is executed, then you should check the logic and debug :) Is the line that writes the log always executed?